# How to accomplish drop-down lists in KIE workbench?

Tags: workflow, jbpm

I'm new to JBPM and am trying to wrap my head around a new project, and recently noticed that while trying to define some user task forms I couldn't find a form option for a drop-down list

At this point my knowledge of the technology is pretty small, and this seems like a strange limitation at first glance, which should have an easy work-around, but I'm having difficulty finding a quick and dirty solution.

Is this something I'd have to code in Eclipse, or something else?

Comment: Have been mulling over this problem and it doesn't look like there's a way to do it in the workbench. However, we're implementing a custom front-end, so we may be able to map a list back to a string input in KIE. I'll have to re-visit this question at a later time to see how that turns out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a select element(drop-down list) look for "Setting a Range Formula" in this part of the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/chap-formmodeler.html#sect-formmodeler-FormulasExpression

Answer (score 10):

The answer that @cego provides is correct for "hard-coded" values, if you want to load dynamic values (from a database for example) you can use the Select Box field type and configure it to use a SelectValuesProvider that calculates the combo values.

To create a SelectValuesProvider you should create a java project with a mvn dependency to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-form-modeler-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Once you did that you can create your class that implements org.jbpm.formModeler.core.config.SelectValuesProvider. This interface provides two methods:

- String getIdentifier(): should return a unique String that identifies this provider. This String will be shown on the Select Box configuration popup.
- Map getSelectOptions(Field field, String value, FormRenderContext renderContext, Locale locale): This method have to return a Map containting the key, text that are going to be load on the Select box. The received parameters are:

  - Field field: the configuration of the field that is going to be evaluated.
  - String Value: the current value of the field
  - FormRenderContext renderContext: a class that contains all the information about the form that is rendered at that moment.
  - Locale locale: the locale in which is being rendered the form.

Once you've created this provider, you must compile your project and put the jar on the server classpath and restart it. After doing that you'll be able to create a form (or edit an existing one), add a Select Box field and choose your provider on the "Data provider" combo box.

Hope it helps, if you have any doubt please ask and I'll try to create an example.

Regards,

Pere

Comment: Thanks Pere. Am investigating how to do this now. In my version of KIE work-bench I don't even notice a select-box field type, just a string type that apparently can be configured into a select-box. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @PereFernandez could you please add description about deploying jar to server and what should be in it? because after all this steps I'm still don't see data provider. May be I should add some attribute to class?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, for old versions you can do it turning a textbox to a combobox using a RangeProvider. This is a very similar solution to the previous one.

First you should create java project with a mvn dependency to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-form-modeler-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After that you have to create your RangeProvider class that implements org.jbpm.formModeler.api.model.RangeProvider and implement it's methods. As the SelectValuesProvider on the previous example this interface provides two methods:
 - String getType(): A unique String to identify the provider
 - Map getRangesMap(String namespace): This method have to return a Map containting the key, text that are going to be load on the combo box. It only receives a String parameter, it is an identifier that allows you to get all the information about the form that is being rendered.

Also you have to create a META-INF/beans.xml file to allow to lookup your provider via CDI (I missed this step on the previous example, sorry).

As the previous example, once you've created the provider you must compile your project and put the jar on the server classpath and restart it.

When the server is started you have to create a new form (or open an existing one), add a TextBox field, edit it's properties and write the string returned by your RangeProvider's getType method on the "Range value" property. 
Save the field properties and if everything is fine the field would be rendered as a combobox showing the values returned by your provider.